# Error with SQLite on android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to add SQLite to my project but I have this error when I send the data to the database

> ```
> > 03-21 18:59:20.742 27050-27050/org.lili14.taps E/SQLiteLog: (1) table
> > Images_table has no column named TAG0 03-21 18:59:20.782
> > 27050-27050/org.lili14.taps E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ...
> >                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Images_table has no
> > column named TAG0 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
> > Images_table(TAG0,URL) VALUES (?,?)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> > Method)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:917)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:528)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> >                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1547)
> >                                                                      at
> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1404)
> >                                                                      at
> > org.lili14.taps.database.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:48)
> >                                                                      at org.lili14.taps.TwoFragment$1.onClick(TwoFragment.java:75)
> >                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
> >                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19869)
> >                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> >                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> >                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
> >                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
> >                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> >                                                                      at
> > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
> >                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
> ```

This is my DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Images.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Images_table";


public static final String col01  = "URL";
public static final String col02 = "TAG0";



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TAG0 TEXT, URL TEXT )");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String url, String tag){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col01, url);
    contentValues.put(col02, tag);
   long result =  db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;

    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}



public Cursor getAllDate(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

}

If I delete the second value in ContentValue work but no save all data 
I want to save just 2 value and auto generate the ID

Answer (score 0):

Try change database version in constructor:

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
```

Comment: it's working man thank you